# Azure Form Recognizer. Migrate v1.0-preview custom models to v2.0

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I am currently migrating from v1.0-preview of Form Recognizer to v2.0 as announced it will be deprecated on 15 September. I've tried analyzing a pdf with v2.0 using a model that I trained in v1.0-preview but the response is that the model does not exist, so I guess I cannot use the old models anymore. I am wondering if it is possible to migrate the trained custom models that I have for v1.0-preview to the v2.0 so that I can use them and not having to retrain them all?

I can see there is an endpoint for copying trained models from one subscription or region to another but nothing is mentioned about migrating models between versions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

v1.0 preview models can't be transferred to v2.0 release. You can use the same blob and documents to train the model in the v2.0 release. Please run the train API and set the labels parameter to false to train a model without labels in the v2 release.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the information. Do you actually know what will happen with the v1.0 preview API after 15 September? Will it stop working completely or it will just stop being supported?

Comment: Please migrate to v2 ASAP and contact support if you have any questions or need assistance.

Comment: @Neta, there is a way to copy one trained model from my subscription to another subscription like a client tenant?

Comment: Yes, you can copy models between resources, regions and subscription. Please see the copy model reference API - 
https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1-preview-2/operations/CopyCustomFormModel

and also a how to guide in our BCRD doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/disaster-recovery